# Connecting Neo4j server with Neo4jPHP gives 401

Tags: php, neo4j, jelastic, neo4jphp

We are just installing our first Neo4j 2.1 application to Jelastic server environment and can't get connection to db working. The simple program (from an answer in [neo4jphp: Cannot instantiate abstract class Everyman\Neo4j\Transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576871/neo4jphp-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-everyman-neo4j-transport)) is this:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Everyman\Neo4j\Client;
$client = new Client($Server_ip_address, 8080);
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

The last row gives an error 401 Unauthorized:

> 'Unable to retrieve server info [401]:\nHeaders: Array
>   (
>       [WWW-Authenticate] =>  Basic realm="neo4j graphdb"
>       [Content-Type] =>  text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>       [Cache-Control] =>  must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>       [Content-Length] =>  0
>       [Server] =>  Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
>   )
>   Body: Array
>   (
>   )
>   '.

Should I configure the user_id/password somewhere in my Apache 2.2 environment, or is there something else missing?

Thanks after all! **The working version** is this:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');   
use Everyman\Neo4j\Client;
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client($host, $port);
$client->getTransport()
  ->setAuth($username, $password);
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

Also "->useHttps()" should be used, if you don't have a trusted environment.

Comment: I have found no examples how credentials should be given, normally they are not expressed. 

The documents in http://jadell.github.io/neo4jphp/docs/index.html tell that there is a function Transport.setAuth($user, $passwd), but it is not good idea to hard code these. Is there any other ways to set the credentials in for example php.ini?

Comment: I tried to use the setAuth method, but it fails: "Cannot instantiate abstract class Everyman\\Neo4j\\Transport". I wrote ` $client = new Client(new Transport('10.50.8.204', 8080).setAuth('admin', $mypasswd));`

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a new Transport. The `setAuth` method is called on the $client. You are correct that you should never hardcode security credentials into an application. You can store the username/password anywhere you normally store credentials to read into your application securely: config files, Apache environment vars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using authentication, you need to pass along the username/password, as shown in the example at https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Getting-started#testing-your-connection

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Everyman\Neo4j\Client;
$client = new Client($Server_ip_address, 8080);
$client->setAuth($username, $password);
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

Additionally, if you are using HTTPS (recommended if you are using authentication) you should also do:

```
$client->useHttps();
```